# Collision Detection Errors and Lagging movement

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, game-physics

this is my first time doing this and im sorry if im doing this wrong but for the last couple of weeks i've been working on a little project with xna and c# while following a book
i made a simple platformer game with enemies and collectibales and traps
but i ran into an issue...

You see i have struggled to find (and to write) a good collision detection function to use. I ultimately used one from the Microsoft platformer project in addition to the function found in the book i was reading everything was fine but i noticed that the game character was lagging (sort of moving in bursts instead of smooth motion) while moving. The frame rate was stable and well above 400 (i turned off fixed time step).

So my question is if someone can take a look at my code and tell me whats the problem..
i think the main problem is in the HandleCollisons function or the horizontal and vertical collision detecting functions

ps: english is not my first language as you might have noticed so sorry for the bad grammer :D/>
anyway thanks in advance

this is the class that does the collision Detection :

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        Vector2 prevLocation = worldLocation;

        if (useGravity) { speed.Y += Gravity.Y * elapsed; }

        Vector2 moveAmount;
        moveAmount.X = speed.X * elapsed;
        moveAmount.Y = speed.Y * elapsed;

        if (isPlayer)
        {
            moveAmount = horizontalCollisionTest(moveAmount);
            moveAmount = verticalCollisionTest(moveAmount);
        }
        if (moveAmount == Vector2.Zero)
        {
            worldLocation = prevLocation;
        }
        else
        {
            worldLocation.X += moveAmount.X;
            worldLocation.Y += moveAmount.Y;
        }

        HandleCollisions();

        if (limitSpeed)
        {
            if (speed.X > maxSpeed.X) speed.X = maxSpeed.X;
            if (speed.X < -maxSpeed.X) speed.X = -maxSpeed.X;
            if (speed.Y > maxSpeed.Y) speed.Y = maxSpeed.Y;
            if (speed.Y < -maxSpeed.Y) speed.Y = -maxSpeed.Y;
        }

        if ((speed.Y > MaxSpeed.Y / 20))
        {
            onGround = false;
            jumping = true;
        }

        if (!beingMoved)
        {
            if (speed.X < 0) speed.X += deaccelerationX * elapsed;
            if (speed.X > 0) speed.X -= deaccelerationX * elapsed;

            if (speed.X > 0 && speed.X < (deaccelerationX * elapsed)) speed.X = 0;
            if (speed.X < 0 && speed.X > (-deaccelerationX * elapsed)) speed.X = 0;
        }

        if (worldLocation.X <= 0)
        {
            worldLocation.X = 0;
            speed.X = 0;
        }
        if (worldLocation.X >= (Camera.WorldRectangle.Width - FrameWidth))
        {
            worldLocation.X = Camera.WorldRectangle.Width - FrameWidth;
            speed.X = 0;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    private void HandleCollisions()
    {
        Rectangle bounds = CollisionRectangle;
        int left = (int)((bounds.Left / TileMap.TileWidth)) * TileMap.TileWidth;
        int right = (int)((bounds.Right / TileMap.TileWidth)) * TileMap.TileWidth;

        int top = (int)((bounds.Top / TileMap.TileHeight)) * TileMap.TileHeight;
        int bottom = (int)((bounds.Bottom / TileMap.TileHeight)) * TileMap.TileHeight;

        for (int i = left; i <= right; i += TileMap.TileWidth)
        {
            for (int j = top; j <= bottom; j += TileMap.TileHeight)
            {
                Rectangle tile = TileMap.CellWorldRectangle(i / TileMap.TileWidth, j / TileMap.TileHeight);

                if (!TileMap.CellIsPassable(TileMap.GetCellByPixel(new Vector2(i, j))))
                {
                    Rectangle tileRect = new Rectangle(i, j, TileMap.TileWidth, TileMap.TileHeight);
                    Vector2 depth = RectangleExtensions.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds, tileRect);

                    if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
                    {
                        float absDepthX = Math.Abs(depth.X);
                        float absDepthY = Math.Abs(depth.Y);

                        if (absDepthY <= absDepthX)
                        {
                            if (preBottom <= tileRect.Top)
                            {
                                onGround = true;
                                jumping = false;
                            }
                            if (onGround)
                            {
                                worldLocation = new Vector2(worldLocation.X, worldLocation.Y + depth.Y + 1);
                                bounds = CollisionRectangle;
                                speed.Y = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            worldLocation = new Vector2(worldLocation.X + depth.X, worldLocation.Y);
                            bounds = CollisionRectangle;
                            speed.X = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        preBottom = bounds.Bottom;
    }

    private Vector2 horizontalCollisionTest(Vector2 moveAmount)
    {
        if (moveAmount.X == 0)
            return moveAmount;

        Rectangle afterMoveRect = CollisionRectangle;
        afterMoveRect.Offset((int)moveAmount.X, -5);
        Vector2 corner1, corner2;

        if (moveAmount.X < 0)
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left,
                                  afterMoveRect.Top + 1);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left,
                                  afterMoveRect.Bottom - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right,
                                  afterMoveRect.Top + 1);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right,
                                  afterMoveRect.Bottom - 1);
        }

        Vector2 mapCell1 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner1);
        Vector2 mapCell2 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner2);

        if (!TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell1) ||
            !TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell2))
        {
            moveAmount.X = 0;
            speed.X = 0;
        }

        return moveAmount;
    }

    private Vector2 verticalCollisionTest(Vector2 moveAmount)
    {
        if (moveAmount.Y == 0)
            return moveAmount;

        Rectangle afterMoveRect = CollisionRectangle;
        afterMoveRect.Offset((int)moveAmount.X, (int)moveAmount.Y + 1);
        Vector2 corner1, corner2;

        if (moveAmount.Y < 0)
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left + 1,
                                  afterMoveRect.Top);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right - 1,
                                  afterMoveRect.Top);
        }
        else
        {
            corner1 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Left + 1,
                                  afterMoveRect.Bottom);
            corner2 = new Vector2(afterMoveRect.Right - 1,
                                  afterMoveRect.Bottom);
        }

        Vector2 mapCell1 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner1);
        Vector2 mapCell2 = TileMap.GetCellByPixel(corner2);

        if (!TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell1) ||
            !TileMap.CellIsPassable(mapCell2))
        {
            if (moveAmount.Y > 0)
            {
                onGround = true; 
            }
            moveAmount.Y = 0;
            speed.Y = 0;
        }            

        return moveAmount;
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        base.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

}

and the code for the rectangle intersection depth is :

```
public static Vector2 GetIntersectionDepth(this Rectangle rectA, Rectangle rectB)
    {
        // Calculate half sizes.
        float halfWidthA = rectA.Width / 2.0f;
        float halfHeightA = rectA.Height / 2.0f;
        float halfWidthB = rectB.Width / 2.0f;
        float halfHeightB = rectB.Height / 2.0f;

        // Calculate centers.
        Vector2 centerA = new Vector2(rectA.Left + halfWidthA, rectA.Top + halfHeightA);
        Vector2 centerB = new Vector2(rectB.Left + halfWidthB, rectB.Top + halfHeightB);

        // Calculate current and minimum-non-intersecting distances between centers.
        float distanceX = centerA.X - centerB.X;
        float distanceY = centerA.Y - centerB.Y;
        float minDistanceX = halfWidthA + halfWidthB;
        float minDistanceY = halfHeightA + halfHeightB;

        // If we are not intersecting at all, return (0, 0).
        if (Math.Abs(distanceX) >= minDistanceX || Math.Abs(distanceY) >= minDistanceY)
            return Vector2.Zero;

        // Calculate and return intersection depths.
        float depthX = distanceX > 0 ? minDistanceX - distanceX : -minDistanceX - distanceX;
        float depthY = distanceY > 0 ? minDistanceY - distanceY : -minDistanceY - distanceY;
        return new Vector2(depthX, depthY);
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Edit your post and add a small amount of code that shows the problem that you are having. This isn't a place where someone will analyze your entire codebase looking for problems, so you have to make all efforts to show precisely what is wrong.

Comment: The request was for a SMALL amount of code... Not all of that code is relevant.

Comment: i re edited the question to include only the update function and the relevent functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled all collisions and left only movement player was still jittering. SO! I have started to dig into movement and found that the player speed is stable at maximum speed and do not vary it means no cause jitter again. SO! Next my step was digging around a camera and I think i have found what are you looking for! Seems you are calculating a camera reposition at player input before all other code movement calculation etc. and it cause jitter.
I did reposition() method after base.Update() ( after all code of movement being processed) and I think it works!
Here is a little change of a code in the Player.cs Update method. Watch at repositionCamera(); placement at the code:

```
    public class Player : MovingGameObject
    {
    ...
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        this.beingMoved = false;

        if (canBeDameged)
        {
            if (!canTakeDamage)
            {
                timeSinceDamage += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
                if (timeSinceDamage >= damegeDelay)
                {
                    canTakeDamage = true;
                    timeSinceDamage = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        if (hasInput)
        {
            string newAnimation = "Stand";

            if (Input.KeyDown(leftKey0) ||
                Input.KeyDown(leftKey1))
            {
                speed.X -= accelerationX * elapsed;
                beingMoved = true;
                flipped = true;
                newAnimation = "Walk";
            }
            if (Input.KeyDown(rightKey0) ||
                Input.KeyDown(rightKey1))
            {
                speed.X += accelerationX * elapsed;
                beingMoved = true;
                flipped = false;
                newAnimation = "Walk";
            }
            if ((Input.KeyPressed(jumpKey0) ||
                Input.KeyPressed(jumpKey1) ||
                Input.KeyPressed(jumpKey2)))
            {
                Jump();
                newAnimation = "Jump";
            }
            if ((Input.KeyDown(downKey0) ||
                Input.KeyDown(downKey1)))
            {
                speed.Y += Gravity.Y * 3 * elapsed;
            }
            HandelAnimations(newAnimation);

            //repositionCamera(); --> replace it after base.Update(gameTime)
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);

        repositionCamera(); // place here!
    }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collision detection is awesome. In my 2d game I use simple XNA rectangles (bounds of a texture). The world has many different blocks (64x64 textures with rectangles) and I use simple wrapping textures to increase the size of a block then I check whether the rectangle of a character was intersected with any world rectangle by calling character.rectangle.Intersects(world.rectangles[i]) into the loop of world rectangles.

Seems your loops are expensive for your game Update() method:

```
        for (int i = left; i <= right; i += TileMap.TileWidth)
        {
           for (int j = top; j <= bottom; j += TileMap.TileHeight)
           {
              ...
           }
        }
```

To optimize this **LARGE loop** which probably cause **FPS drops** I use **QuadTree**.

[Read this about quadtree which optimize collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)

You can use different algorithms such as Octree, BinaryTree, BSP etc. but quadtree is the best choise for 2d space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
i will look into quad trees 
but my problem is not fps drops... when moving the player it seems to jitter while moving even while in mid air although my fps is well above 400fps
anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: If you can share your project for me I can help further with this issue.

Comment: also do you have any links for some implementation of quad trees in c# and xna ? if so it would be great if you could share them with me

Comment: Ok no worry I have my own 2D engine I wrote on XNA almost completed (very very big project it is enough for me I don't need someones else). I downloaded and reply soon, delete the link to prevent downloading of someone else.

Comment: You have jitter only when player collides with level or even when he is  simply moving?

Comment: i notice jittering when the player is moving or jumping 
it seems to me like the collision detecting functions stop the player and move him again and so .... i maybe wrong but i dont know what is happening... could it be because im using the same heavy functions to update the positions of the enemies in the level ? 
if so i think i can write a simpler function for them

Comment: I have found some issue with HandleCollisions() method and your in-game player. When player collides it cause jitter as well. Seems your player has already collision detection using horizontalCollisionTest(moveAmount), verticalCollisionTest(moveAmount) methods:

try this little edit:
            if (!isPlayer)
                HandleCollisions();
Try before and after intersect with a wall. I will try to solve your main problem soon.

Comment: ok,
btw if use that method ( HandleCollisions) because of one issue...if you stand on the left side of a tile and move just a bit to the left the player wont fall but instead will slowly fall through the tile
thanks alot for your help so far